I want to reauthenticate the feathers client user when I refresh?
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Application, feathers } from '@feathersjs/feathers';
import socketioClient from '@feathersjs/socketio-client';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.prod';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FeathersService {
  app!: Application;
  socket;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3030');
    this.app = feathers()
      .configure(socketioClient(this.socket))
      .configure(feathers);

    this.socket.on('connect', () => console.log('Server connected'));

    this.socket.on('connect_error', (err: any) => {});

     this.reauthenticate();
  }
  

  on(event: string, serviceName: string, callback: (data: any) => void) {
    this.app.service(serviceName).on(event, callback);
  }

  async reauthenticate() {
    try {
      const accessToken = await this.decryptToken();

      if (!accessToken) {
        console.log('No token found.');
        sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        return;
      }
      await this.app.service('authentication').create({
        strategy: 'jwt',
        accessToken: accessToken,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  decryptToken(): string {
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      localStorage.getItem('token') || sessionStorage.getItem('token') || '',
      environment.secretKey
    ).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }
}


 async logIn(loginCredentials: any): Promise<any> {
    try {
      // const login = await this.feathers.app.authenticate({
      //   strategy: 'local',
      //   ...loginCredentials,
      // });
      const login = await this.feathers.app
        .service('authentication')
        .create({ strategy: 'local', ...loginCredentials });
      console.log(login);

      if (login['accessToken']) {
        if (loginCredentials.keepmeLogin) {
          localStorage.setItem(
            'token',
            CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
              login['accessToken'],
              environment.secretKey
            ).toString()
          );
        } else {
          sessionStorage.setItem(
            'token',
            CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
              login['accessToken'],
              environment.secretKey
            ).toString()
          );
        }
      }

I dont want to use feathers/authentication because i will store the token in local or session storage. So i want to manually handle the token on initiall login it fetch the data from the feathers server but when i refresh it throws error like not authentication. so i try to reauthticate the user but still it was fail.
